# Yii 2 and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

Due project requirements I have to use a different version of jQuery than the one which comes with Yii2. I know I can disable it by using:

```
'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            // you can override AssetBundle configs here       
             'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,
                'js' => [] 
            ],        
        ],
    ],
```

Then I go to AppAsset:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = "@app/themes/v1/assets";

    public $jsOptions = [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END ];

    public $js = [
        "js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js",

    ]; 
}
```

But this brings one big issue, jquery loads after yii.validation, etc:

```
</script><script src="/assets/5b466ff1/yii.js?v=1465857632"></script>
<script src="/assets/5b466ff1/yii.validation.js?v=1465857632"></script>
<script src="/assets/5b466ff1/yii.activeForm.js?v=1465857632"></script>
<script src="/assets/98d185b3/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js?v=1466702133"></script>
```

My temporal solution is changing POS_END to POS_HEAD, but that affects page SEO right?, as far as I know is considered bad practice to load js on head.

So my question is:

How can I load jQuery from my theme assets, using POS_END and loading before yii.validation etc?

A possibility is to add it on web/js/jquery.js but I would prefer to keep it on the assets bundle.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Adding this to AppAsset allows me to have control on the theme itself. It is cleaner than modifying the global config.

```
public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\\web\\JqueryAsset'] = [
            'js' => ['lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js'],
            'sourcePath' => '@app/themes/v1/assets/js'
        ];

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Change Your Config Code as :

```
'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'js' => ['lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js'],
                'sourcePath' => '@app/themes/v1/assets/js'
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

No Need to Define `jquery` in AppAsset

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
  public $sourcePath = "@app/themes/v1/assets";
  public $jsOptions = [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END ];
  public $js = [
    //"js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js" Not Required
  ]; 
}
```